# Apply JSON_VALUE for a json where the key is GUID

Tags: sql, json, t-sql

I have this json

```
@json='{ "8d2059c9-6805-441e-8c6e-e266c6991d51": "9dce67af-2b38-45bd-822f-d1d5e210edb9" }';
```

I want to apply Transact-SQL select:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.8d2059c9-6805-441e-8c6e-e266c6991d51')
```

I can't do this because my key is a guid ( starts with 8 and contains - )

How can I do this?

Comment: And if so you may need to use [`SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."8d2059c9-6805-441e-8c6e-e266c6991d51"')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) not `JSON_QUERY`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here.

Firstly, since your JSON property name `8d2059c9-6805-441e-8c6e-e266c6991d51` starts with a number and contains the `-` character, you need to surround it with quotes as mentioned in *[JSON Path Expressions (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH)*:

> If the key name starts with a dollar sign or contains special characters such as spaces, surround it with quotes.

Secondly, be sure to use [`SELECT JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than [`SELECT JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  `JSON_VALUE`

> Extracts a **scalar value** from a JSON string.

Whereas `JSON_QUERY`

> Extracts an **object or an array** from a JSON string.

Since your JSON value is a string, the former is required.

Thus your query should be:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."8d2059c9-6805-441e-8c6e-e266c6991d51"')
```